# username rendering after login in place of signup button

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

**What I'm trying to do is that I want to remove the joining button after user login and add username in place of it.**

here is home.hbs

```
 {{#if isAuthenticated}}
      <li id="user-button" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded my-3">
        <a href="#" class="shy640-sub-ddown">{{username}}</a>
        <ul class="shy640-sub-menu">
          <li id="dashboard"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
 {{else}}
      <li id="join-button" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded my-3">
        <a href="#" class="shy640-sub-ddown">Join</a>
        <ul class="shy640-sub-menu">
          <li id="register-button"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
          <li id="login-button"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
 {{/if}}
```

Here is login router

```
    router.post('/users/login',async (req,res) => {
         try{
           const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.emailphone , req.body.password);
           const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
           res.redirect('/');
         }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            res.status(400).send(e);
         }
    });
```

Here is page rendering code

```
    app.get('',(req, res) => {
       console.log(req.user);
       res.render('home', {
           title: 'Foundation | Home',
       });
    });
```

Comment: How does `isAuthenticated` in your `home.hbs` template get set?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to apply the condition in `home.hbs` you'll need to send `isAuthenticated` into it, like this:

```js
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
       const isAuthenticated = // <--- This variable depends of what auth strategy you are using

       res.render('home', {
           title: 'Foundation | Home',
           isAuthenticated,
       });
});
```